# Pool requests vs batched request

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the Async library `mapLimit/queue` methods and this `aysnc/await` batched request function.

For this example let's say an API has a limit of 20 request per second. I am using this script. My intention is to do the maximum allowed request per second simultaneously.

Am I achieving that with this script?

```js
const data = Array(200).fill('');
const concurrent = 20;
let requests = 0;
const start = new Date();

(async () => {
  
  while (data.length) {
    
    // Batched concurret request per second
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    const batch = data.splice(0, concurrent).map(API);
    const results = await Promise.allSettled(batch);

    // For testing
    const timeTotal = Math.round((requests / (new Date() - start)) * 1000);
    console.log(`Requests per second (total): ${timeTotal}/${data.length}`);

    // Deal with errors
    for (const { status, reason } of results) {
      if (status === 'rejected') {
        console.error(`There was an error ${reason}`);
      }
    }
  }
})()

async function API() {
  requests++;
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}
```

Are the aforementioned methods doing the same thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Batching does create "peaks" of up to 20 concurrent requests, but waits for all requests of the current batch before starting the next batch. So if 1 of the 20 takes very long it will have only that running.

In contrast, solutions like `mapLimit` start 20 requests, and then 1 additional for each that finishes, so there are always 20 requests in flight at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to do that with my function? Or in your opinion I am better off with async mapLimit?

Comment: Oh wait I totally misunderstood your question. You want a "*limit of 20 request per second*", not a limit of "20 requests at the same time*"

Comment: I actually want both, the API has a limit of 20 per second, so I want to make sure I send 20 simultaneusly per second. What happens is that the API takes a long time to respond so the idea of not having to wait for the 20 to complete is quite appealing.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do the same thing I was doing with batches but with pool requests.

I could not find anything that did the same, all the async pool libraries use `Promise.all()` I really wanted to use `Promise.allSettled()` to take advantange of the oportunity to rerun a request on a given condition.

I have tried `p-limit` but in the end I went for `tiny-async-pool` and modified the [source code](https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool/blob/master/lib/es7.js) to match my batch request:

```js
export async function asyncPool(poolLimit, array, iteratorFn, exception) {
  const promises = []
  const racers = []

  for (const [index, item] of array.entries()) {
    process.stdout.write(`\rProcessing ${index + 1}/${array.length} ...`)
    const pro = Promise.resolve().then(() => iteratorFn(item, array))
    promises.push(pro)

    if (poolLimit <= array.length) {
      const racer = pro.then(() => racers.splice(racers.indexOf(racer), 1))
      racers.push(racer)
      if (racers.length >= poolLimit) {
        await Promise.race(racers).catch(() => false)
      }
    }
  }

  const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

  for (const { status, reason } of results) {
    if (status === 'rejected') {
      const { name, error } = reason
      if (name === exception) await asyncPool(poolLimit, [error], iteratorFn)
    }
  }
}
```